# Incremental compressed backup over ssh

Tags: ssh, backup

So far I'm backing up my stuff using:

```
rsync -avz --delete /Local/Location/of/data/ -e ssh username@hostname:/Remote/Location/of/backup
```

The local side is running Mac OS, and the server side is running Linux. I cannot change this setting.

This works great (as far as I can tell) and transfers only the differences since the last backup, as well as preserving all the permissions etc. However, this approach has one drawback, namely the backup on the server's side is not compressed (and therefore I get warnings). How can I add some compression of the process' end result?

The naive approach would be to (given the destination is compressed):

1. Uncompress the destination
2. rsync the differences from local to remote
3. Compress the backup on the server's side.

What would be the best practice here?

### Edit

I came across the notion of "Incremental Dumps". Seems like `tar` can be helpful here. Is this a way to go?

Comment: Try to use some filesystem that does compression.

Comment: @Cougar You cannot always influence the destination filesystem

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a compressing file system on the server side. See "[Allocation and layout policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Allocation_and_layout_policies)" in Wikipedia's "Comparison of file systems" for a list.

Another option is to use a filesystem which offers snapshots or copy-on-write. `btrfs` would be a good candidate for this since it offers everything but one tiny feature: It's not safe enough for backups, yet. Don't get me wrong: btrfs is great; I'm using it for about a year, now, and never had problems. But backups need to be *reliable* first and foremost.

Also you often cannot simply create a partition on a server with a file system of your liking. There are two workarounds:

1. You can create a huge file on the server and create the file system in there (just give `mkfs` the path to the file instead of a device name). Afterwards, you can mount this file system using `mount -o loop` *file mount-point*
2. If that's not an option but you have [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (Filesystem in Userspace) enabled in the server (it's a kernel module), then you can use [lessfs](http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/).

Lastly, you could use a dedicated backup tool for this task. There are many options (like [dar](http://dar.linux.free.fr/), [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) or google for "[linux backup](https://www.google.ch/search?q=linux%20backup)"). But be warned: I searched many years, tried many options and still haven't found anything that is as simple as `rsync` and a powerful file system.